# How do I place a multigroup in another multigroup?

Tags: entities

Is there any workaround to be able to place a multigroup inside another multigroup using CCK?

This is what CCK tells me when I try to do it:

> You cannot place any kind of group inside a multigroup.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, CCK Multigroup is succeeded by [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection), which can be used to nest collections within collections.

In Drupal 6 however, you already have your answer. You cannot place any kind of group inside a multigroup, due to the way the information is stored in the database.